# How to send a function over sockets python

Tags: python, sockets, client-server

so I am learning about sockets, specifically client server networks, and a question I have is that would it be possible to send a function over sockets?

I know that you could do something like this:

```
#class containing function, called printing_class
print.py
class printing_class(self):

def print(self):
    print("hello world")
```

```
#server.py
from print import printing_class

print = printing_class(self)
server.send(print) #pseudocode for send statement, sending print object
```

```
#client.py
print = client.receive() #pseudo code for print and receive
print.print() # by doing this, prints out hello world
```

By sending an object, I could access its methods then print it.

However, i was wondering is there a way to do it like this:

```
#server.py
server.send(print("hello world"))
```

```
#client.py
client.receive() # when receiving from server, automatically prints it
```

Would it be possible to send a print function over sockets, and when the client receives it, it would automatically print it?

Comment: Everything is _possible_. There is no simple way to do this and this should not ever be done. But it is possible and a server which would allow it would have a serious security hole and deserves to be destroyed by hackers ;)

Comment: Oh when you put it that way, I do get the implications of it now, thank you for the explanation!

Comment: FluidLight proved me wrong in an answer. This is in fact simple to do. As for the security, you could (and should) add a security layer preventing anyone to access the server...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved using a library called [RPyC](https://rpyc.readthedocs.io/en/latest/).

1. Run the included `rpyc_classic.py` script for a simple server (just for testing).
2. Connect to it using a client and send the python code you'd like to be executed.

**Example:**

```
import rpyc
c = rpyc.classic.connect("localhost") # connect
c.execute("print('hi there')")   # print "hi there" on the host
```

One of the many features of rpyc is that you can limit which functions (or you can define them yourself) to be executed as to not to cause security holes.

Comment: Thank you! Is this the only to do it, or can you do it without a library?

Comment: A simpler way would be to send your python code over to the server and use exec/eval to execute it. But I highly wouldn't recommend due to the obvious security risks involved.